# Why can't I run multiple tasks in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm working on a file processing system where files can be uploaded to S3 and then processed in a container. I have been using triggering ECS to run tasks from lambda and passing a few environment variables.

**S3 -> Lambda -> ECS**

I'm running into a problem where I can't seem to run more than 1 task at once. If a task is already running then any subsequent tasks that get run are stuck in "PROVISIONING" and eventually disappear altogether.

Here is my lambda function that runs the ECS task:

```
const params: RunTaskRequest = {
    launchType: "FARGATE",
    cluster: "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:cluster/FileProcessingCluster",
    taskDefinition: "XXX",
    networkConfiguration: {
        awsvpcConfiguration: {
            subnets: [
                "subnet-XXX",
                "subnet-XXX"
            ],
            securityGroups: [
                "..."
            ],
            assignPublicIp: "DISABLED"
        }
    },
    overrides: {
        containerOverrides: [
            {
                name: "FileProcessingContainer",
                environment: [
                    ...
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
};

try {
    await ecs.runTask(params).promise(); 
}catch (e) {
    console.error(e, e.stack)       
}
```

I'm using AWS-CDK to create the ECS infrastructure:

```
    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'FileProcessingCluster', {
        clusterName: "FileProcessingCluster"
    });

    const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, "FileProcessingTask", {
        memoryLimitMiB: 8192,
        cpu: 4096,
    });

    taskDefinition.addContainer("FileProcessingContainer", {
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset("../local-image"),
        logging: new ecs.AwsLogDriver({
            streamPrefix: `${id}`
        }),
        memoryLimitMiB: 8192,
        cpu: 4096,
    });
```

Is there some something I'm missing here? Perhaps a setting related to concurrent tasks?

Comment: Can you check if there are any details on the problem in the ECS event log? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-event-messages.html

Comment: Just a lot of  'service my-service has reached a steady state.' events

Comment: I believe could be due to a misconfiguration of scaling options

Comment: Are you starting an ECS "service" or a "task"? Given your description, it sounds like you should be using tasks, not a service, and not setting any scaling settings at all. If you were sending S3 events to SQS, the you could use a service that auto-scales based on the number of items in the queue. You should probably add your Lambda code to your question.

Comment: I'm starting tasks, but I also have a service. If I'm honest I don't completely understand the whole thing given I just started with it yesterday. So you're saying I don't need a service and could simply run tasks?

Comment: I just want to be able to run as many tasks as I want without any limitations. Once the processing is done then the tasks shuts down and that's it.

Comment: I have no idea if you need a service or not, why are you running both? Do you have multiple applications running in the same ECS cluster? To process your S3 events, your Lambda function should be creating tasks, not services.

Comment: My guess is you may be hitting an account limit on the number of Fargate tasks you can run, but we won't know for sure until you find the actual error message in the ECS logs.

Comment: My lambda is running tasks, not services. I was following some example AWS CDK templates which used a service, I'm not sure if or why I needed it though.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I misconfigured the subnets in the task definition, this was preventing the image pull from ECR.

You can read more about it here:
[ECS task not starting - STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: “Error response from daemon request canceled while waiting for connection”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686844/ecs-task-not-starting-stopped-cannotpullcontainererror-error-response-from)

And:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-pull-container-error/

Comment: I can't mark this as correct since I don't have enough rep.